# insert null date interbase

Tags: database, date, null, interbase

I need to insert a null or '00/00/00' date value.

Is it possible to do it on interbase?

I already tried to insert '00/00/00' and it wasn't possible.

Comment: That last sentence is incomplete. What exactly *have* you tried?

Comment: Retracted my answer, since I obviously can't read the question properly. Sorry...

Comment: A NULL date and a date of '00/00/00' are NOT the same. The first is a NULL date, and the second is an invalid (but not NULL) date.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the literature](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/IBXEUpdate1/EmbedSQL.pdf) (I have zero experience with InterBase) you can use standard SQL 
see section 6-56 "NULLing columns with UPDATE"

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET DATEVALUE = NULL
WHERE SOME_ID = 123
```

you might have more options depending on your client